# URL amigable usando controladores

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, controller

Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer en .htaccess o como sea para que en la URL en vez de aparecer:

https://frontendtools.net/v/exec?u=Bucle-for-sin-index

aparezca esta URL amigable:

https://frontendtools.net/Bucle-for-sin-index

Estoy utilizando controladores con PHP donde v es viewController y exec es el action que llama al modelo y muestra el contenido que se imprime en la vista.

En mi htaccess tengo:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+)\/(.+)(\/)?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA]
```

Necesito saber qué más tengo que poner para que muestre la URL amigable como he dicho antes.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Me parece que estás entendiendo mal el concepto. El `mod_rewrite` no hace que la URL `X` *aparezca* como `Y`. Lo que hace es que al *escribir* la URL `Y` *cargue* la `X`. Es decir, si querés ver la URL amigable, tenés que escribir la URL amigable. Tu trabajo es a partir de esa información levantar la primera URL. Todas tus URLs son `/v/exec?u=`?

Answer (score 1):

Para que la url sea amigable debe constar de dos partes el `.htaccess` y el `index`

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://midominio.com/$1/ [R=301,L,QSA]

    Rewriterule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/$ ?controlador=$1&accion=$2&id=$3 [L]
    Rewriterule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ ?controlador=$1&accion=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ ?controlador=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'model/database.php';

$controller = 'predeterminadoController';

// Todo esta lógica hara el papel de un FrontController
if(!isset($_REQUEST['controlador']))
{
    require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";
    $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller;
    $controller->Index();    
}
else
{
    // Obtenemos el controlador que queremos cargar
    $controller = strtolower($_REQUEST['controlador']);
    $accion = isset($_REQUEST['accion']) ? $_REQUEST['accion'] : 'Index';

    // Instanciamos el controlador
    require_once "controller/$controller.controller.php";
    $controller = ucwords($controller) . 'Controller';
    $controller = new $controller;

    // Llama la accion
    call_user_func( array( $controller, $accion ) );
}
```

El `htaccess` se encargara de meter cada parte de la url en una variable que podra controlar desde el `index.php`. Por ejemplo:

Para `/alumno/actualizar` alumno seria el controlador y actualizar seria la acción